# How to save data in the GRIB format with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, savechanges, grib

I have a matrix of 275 lines by 535 columns of atmospheric data in MATLAB. How do I save this data in the GRIB format? The lines are the geographical coordinates and the columns are the forecast times.